# Below what temperature does a semiconductor stop behaving intrinsically?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I understand that for an intrinsic semiconductor $n=p$ where $n$ is the electron carrier concentration and $p$ is the hole concentration. My question is how to calculate the temperature at which the semiconductor is no longer intrinsic?

The electron carrier concentration is given by,
$$n = N_c exp[\frac{\mu - E_g}{k_B T}]$$ where $E_g$ is the band gap energy, whilst
$$p=N_v exp[\frac{-\mu}{k_B T}]$$

We are also told that the intrinsic carrier concentration at $300K$ is $2 \text{x} 10^{16} m^{-3}$
Assuming that the density of states $N_v ,N_c$ are constant, surely we can't just equate these and solve for $T$, as they already presuppose the semiconductor is intrinsic?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If there are no dopants it is always intrinsic - just the equilibrium carrier concentrations change with temperature.

Comment: I am working through the book "Solid State Physics" by Hook and Hall, and one of the questions states that a sample of silicon is purified until it only contains 10^18 donor atoms, and the asks at what temperature it ceases to show intrinsic behaviour?

Comment: 10^18 isn't exactly low.  So, at what temperature would the intrinsic concentration drop below 10^18?

Comment: Sorry, please see my edits. Can we say that n+p = 10^18?